# scala Iterable#map vs. Iterable#flatMap

Tags: scala, monads, scala-collections

What is the difference between the `map` and `flatMap` functions of `Iterable`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a pretty good explanation:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-collections-for-the-easily-bored-part-2

Using  list as an example:

Map's signature is:

```
map [B](f : (A) => B) : List[B]
```

and flatMap's is

```
flatMap [B](f : (A) => Iterable[B]) : List[B]
```

So flatMap takes a type [A] and returns an iterable type [B] and map takes a type [A] and returns a type [B]

This will also give you an idea that flatmap will "flatten" lists.

```
val l  = List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,4))

println(l.map(_.toString)) // changes type from list to string
// prints List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))

println(l.flatMap(x => x)) // "changes" type list to iterable
// prints List(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that `l flatMap { x => x }` is *precisely* equivalent to `l.flatten` according to the monadic axioms.  FlatMap is Scala's equivalent of the monadic `bind` operation (>>= in Haskell).  I find it to be most useful on non-collections monads such as Option.  When in conjunction with collections, it is most useful for implementing "nested map-loops", returning a collection as a result.

Comment: Well said.  The chaining of Options is much better to work with than a bunch of statements like if(x != null and x.foo != null).

http://blog.lostlake.org/index.php?/archives/50-The-Scala-Option-class-and-how-lift-uses-it.html discusses this in detail

Comment: println(l.flatMap(x => x)) this doesn't work anymore and flatMap needs to be used like that : http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p07.scala

Answer (score 58):

The above is all true, but there is one more thing that is handy:  `flatMap` turns a `List[Option[A]]` into `List[A]`, with any `Option` that drills down to `None`, removed.  This is a key conceptual breakthrough for getting beyond using `null`.

Comment: Aw, that's another nice trick with Option I never thought about. I just had a method return a list of 1 or more things, never saw the `Option.toList` method:

    List( Some( "foo" ), None, Some( "bar" ) ).flatMap( _.toList )

Comment: Or perhaps even better, use `Option.toIterator` with Tristan's method so that you don't iterate over the whole list until necessary.

Answer (score 8):

From [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/index.html):

- map

> Returns the iterable resulting
>   from applying the given function f to
>   each element of this iterable.

- flatMap

> Applies the given function f
>   to each element of this iterable, then
>   concatenates the results.

Comment: I'm looking a little more analysis/explanation.

Comment: OK, so change your question to be more specific. Say what you already know, and what you need clarifying.

Comment: I liked your snippy comment better.

Comment: Me too, but I figured discretion is the better part of valour :)

Answer (score 8):

```
lines.map(line => line split "\\W+") // will return a list of arrays of words
lines.flatMap(line => line split "\\W+") // will return a list of words
```

You can see this better in for comprehensions:

```
for {line <- lines
     word <- line split "\\W+"}
yield word.length
```

this translates into:

```
lines.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W+").map(word => word.length))
```

Each iterator inside for will be translated into a "flatMap", except the last one, which gets translated into a "map". This way, instead of returning nested collections (a list of an array of a buffer of blah, blah, blah), you return a flat collection. A collection formed by the elements being yield'ed -- a list of Integers, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Look here:
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-collections-for-the-easily-bored-part-2

"Search for flatMap"  - there is a really good explanation of it there.  (Basically it is a combination of "flatten" and "map" -- features from other languages).