# Filtering lists of generic types

Tags: java, generics, guava, iterable

Lists or Iterables can be filtered easily using guavas [`filter(Iterable<?> unfiltered, Class<T> type)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29). This operation performs two tasks: the list is filtered *and* transformed into a sequence of the given type T.

Quite often however I end up with `Iterables<Something<?>>`
and I want to get a subsequence of `Iterables<Something<T>>` for some specialized T.

It is clear, that Guava can't solve this problem out of the box due to type erasure: `Something<T>` does not provide any direct information about its T.

Lets say I have something like `S<? extends Number>`. 
If I am able to define some predicate which tells me if `S<?>` may be casted to `S<Double>` I may use it as a filer:

```
<T extends Number> Predicate<S<?>> isOfType(Class<N> type) {...}
```

with:

```
Iterable<S<?>> numbers;
Iterable<S<?>> filtered = Iterable.filter(numbers, isOfType(Double.class));
```

This performs the task of filtering but it misses the transformation step.
If I think my Predicate works well I may even think of casting:

```
Iterable<S<Double>> doubles = (Iterable<S<Double>>) filtered;
```

But this exposes some ugly cast operation.

As an alternative I may provide a `Function<S<?>, S<Double>>` to perform the cast.
In constrast to [`Class.cast()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) however it should not throw a `ClassCastException` but simply return `null` if the element can not be casted (or transformed).
This way the sequence may be converted without any explicit cast:

```
<T extends Number> Function<S<?>, S<T>> castOrNull(Class<N> type) {...}

Iterable<S<Double>> doubles = Iterable.filter(numbers, castOrNull(Double.class));
```

But the list is not really filtered: instead it still contains null objects for each element which could not converted or casted to `S<Double>`. 
But this may solved easily by an additional filtering step like:

```
Iterable<S<Double>> doubles = Iterables.filter(doubles, Predicates.notNull());
```

The second solution seems much smarter to me. The `Function` to be defined may either perform a cast (which hides the unchecked operation) or it may really create some new Object `S<T>` if necessary.

The remaining question is: 
Is there any smarter way to perform the necessary converting and filtering by a single step? I may simply define some utility function like:

```
<I,O> Iterables<O> convert(
    Iterables<O> input, 
    Function<? super I, ? extends O> convert, 
    Predicate<? super O> filter);

<I,O> Iterables<O> convert(
    Iterables<O> input, 
    Function<? super I, ? extends O> convert);
```

Where the second function is a short cut of the first one with a `Predicates.notNull()`;

But it's worth to have the first function, too, as the predicate is not necessary `Predicates.notNull()`.

Imagine an `Iterable<Iterable<? extends Number>>`. The converter function `Function<Iterable<? extends Number>, Iterable<Double>>` may simply return a filtered sequence which may be empty instead of returning null. The additional filter may finally drop empty sequences using `Iterables.isEmpty()`.

Comment: It would be useful if `Iterable.filter(...)` returns an iterable with extended functionality so you can chain filters. `/* S extends Collection */ Iterable<S<Double>> doubles = Iterable.filter(numbers, castOrNull(Double.class)).filter(Predicates.notNull()).filter(Predicates.notEmpty());`

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single step?  Transformation and filtering are distinct operations.

Answer (score 3):

The monadic approach to this problem is to define an operation that transforms an iterable into an iterable of iterables, by defining a transformation function that for an object of type `T`, returns an object of type `Iterable<T>`. You can then concatenate each iterable to form a single one again. This combination of a mapping followed by a concatenation is called `concatMap` in Haskell and `flatMap` in Scala, and I'm sure it has other names elsewhere.

To implement this, we first create a function that transforms your `S<? extends Number>` into `Iterable<S<Double>>`. This is very similar to your existing function, but our success case is an iterable of one, containing our `S`, and the failure case (our null state) is an empty iterable.

```
<T extends Number> Function<S<?>, Iterable<S<T>>> castOrNull(Class<T> type) {
    return new Function<S<?>, Iterable<S<T>>> {
        @Override
        public Iterable<S<T>> apply(S<?> s) {
            Object contained = s.get();
            if (!(contained instanceof T)) {
                return ImmutableSet.of();
            }

            return ImmutableSet.of(new S<T>(contained));
        }
    };
}
```

We then apply this to the original iterable as you specify above.

```
Iterable<Iterable<S<Double>>> doubleIterables = Iterables.map(numbers, castOrNull(Double.class));
```

We can then concatenate all these together to produce one iterable again, which has all of the desired values and none of those we want to remove.

```
Iterable<S<Double>> doubles = Iterables.concat(doubleIterables);
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried compiling this. You may have to play around with generics to get it to work.*

Comment: Having the function return an Iterable containing zero or one element is a very interesting approach. I hadn't thought of this, and I think it's great that it lets your function return null if needed. Since Guava adds the Optional type in r10 ( http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html ), I wonder if we could use a Function<S<?>, Optional<S<T>>> instead, filtering the resulting Iterable for "present" values.

Comment: I just read luckyjaca's answer, and it seems that's the approach they use in Scala, using the "Option" type, with the added benefit of the flatMap function. See this SO answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059776/scala-iterablemap-vs-iterableflatmap/1060400#1060400 "`flatMap` turns a `List[Option[A]]` into `List[A]`, with any `Option` that drills down to `None`, removed". Pretty cool.

Comment: @eneveu: That would be great if `Optional` implemented `Iterable`, but as far as I'm aware there are no plans to make it so. Nat Pryce's implementation of Maybe in Java (https://github.com/npryce/maybe-java) does, however. A guy at the company I work for forked it and improved it somewhat—you can see that version at https://github.com/youdevise/maybe-java .

Comment: Good point. This means we cannot use `Iterables.concat` to flatten an `Iterable<Optional<T>>` to an `Iterable<T>` of all the present values... I guess we could write an utility method that does this for us, though (or Guava could). On an unrelated note, I would've used `ImmutableSet.of()` in your example to avoid initializing an empty `ArrayList` each time. Something like `return contained instanceof T ? ImmutableSet.of(new S<T>(contained)) : ImmutableSet.of();`. The cool thing is that the empty immutable set is a singleton under the hood, which avoids unnecessary object/array instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Scala language in its collections framework offers similar functionality to Guava. We have Option[T] class which can be considered as at-most-single-element-collection. Among simple filtering or transformation methods there is a method which performs both operations at once. It expects provided transformation function to return a value of Option class. Then it merges content of returned Option objects into a collection. I think you can implement similar functionality in Java.

I was thinking of this problem some time ago because firstly applying transformation and then filtering requires passing the collection twice. Then someone enlightened me that I can transform and filter iterator of this collection. In this case the collection is traversed once and you may apply as many filters and transformations as you want.