# Spark: FlatMapValues query

Tags: apache-spark, flatmap

I'm reading the Learning Spark book and couldn't understand the following pair rdd transformation.

```
rdd.flatMapValues(x => (x to 5))
```

It is applied on an rdd `{(1,2),(3,4),(3,6)}` and the output of the transformation is `{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(3,4),(3,5)}`

Can someone please explain this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`flatMapValues` method is a combination of `flatMap` and `mapValues`.

Let's start with the given rdd.

```
val sampleRDD = sc.parallelize(Array((1,2),(3,4),(3,6)))
```

---

`mapValues` maps the values while keeping the keys.

For example, `sampleRDD.mapValues(x => x to 5)` returns

```
Array((1,Range(2, 3, 4, 5)), (3,Range(4, 5)), (3,Range()))
```

notice that for key-value pair `(3, 6)`, it produces `(3,Range())` since `6 to 5` produces an empty collection of values.

---

`flatMap` "breaks down" collections into the elements of the collection. You can search for more accurate description of flatMap online like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/can-someone-explain-to-me-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-what-is-a-g) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

For example,

given `val rdd2 = sampleRDD.mapValues(x => x to 5)`, 
if we do `rdd2.flatMap(x => x)`, you will get

```
Array((1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(3,4),(3,5)).
```

That is, for every element in the collection in each key, we create a `(key, element)` pair.

Also notice that `(3, Range())` does not produce any additional key element pair since the sequence is empty.

now combining `flatMap` and `mapValues`, you get `flatMapValues`.

Answer (score 5):

flatMapValues works on each value associated with key. In above case `x to 5` means each value will be incremented till 5.

Taking first pair where you have `(1,2)` , here key is 1 and value is 2 so there after applying transformation it will become `{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)}`.

Hope this helps.