# Spark Map transformation

Tags: apache-spark, transformation

Below code will extract data from file and splitting data with comma delimiter.

```
val a=sc.textFile("/sparkinput")
val b=a.map(x=>x.split(","))
b.collect
```

Output:

```
Array(Array(1, Brandon Buckner, avil, female, 525), Array(2, Veda Hopkins, avil, male, 633), Array(3, Zia Underwood, paracetamol, male, 980), Array(4, Austin Mayer, paracetamol, female, 338), Array(5, Mara Higgins, avil, female, 153), Array(6, Sybill Crosby, avil, male, 193), Array(7, Tyler Rosales, paracetamol, male, 778), Array(8, Ivan Hale, avil, female, 454), Array(9, Alika Gilmore, paracetamol, female, 833), Array(10, Len Burgess, metacin, male, 325))


b.saveasTextFile("/sparkoutput")
```

When I save output in textfile not sure why i am getting data as below.
Output:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@45968fc2

[Ljava.lang.String;@6b3012a2

[Ljava.lang.String;@211780a8

[Ljava.lang.String;@dffa691

[Ljava.lang.String;@b1080c5

[Ljava.lang.String;@68760b2f

[Ljava.lang.String;@1dd8703d
```

I am new to spark,please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when using "saveasTextFile" on array of array - this might result in writing Java object instead of string.

I think that using flatMap instead of map might help you get strings in your output-file.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22510434/5088142

Comment: I got the expected result when i use flatmap but i am so curious to know why i didnt get expected out for map.Now i got the answer ..thanks!!

Comment: @Yaron if I may ask about your suggestion to replace `collect` with `collect()` , why ?

Comment: @eliasah - I've removed my comment about collect vs collect()

Comment: @vivman - If I've managed to answer your question please accpet it.