# flatMap() function returns RDD[Char] instead RDD[String]

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand how map and flatMap works but got stuck at below piece of code. flatMap() function returns an RDD[Char] but I was expecting the RDD[String] instead.
Can someone explain why it yields the RDD[Char] ?

```
scala> val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(Array("This is Spark"), Array("It is a processing language"),Array("Very fast"),Array("Memory operations")))

scala> val mapRDD = inputRDD.map(x => x(0))
mapRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[28] at map at <console>:26

scala> mapRDD.collect
res27: Array[String] = Array(This is Spark, It is a processing language, Very fast, Memory operations)

scala> val mapRDD = inputRDD.flatMap(x => x(0))
mapRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Char] = MapPartitionsRDD[29] at flatMap at <console>:26

scala> mapRDD.collect
res28: Array[Char] = Array(T, h, i, s,  , i, s,  , S, p, a, r, k, I, t,  , i, s,  , a,  , p, r, o, c, e, s, s, i, n, g,  , l, a, n, g, u, a, g, e, V, e, r, y,  , f, a, s, t, M, e, m, o, r, y,  , o, p, e, r, a, t, i, o, n, s)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain to me the difference between map and flatMap and what is a good use case for each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/can-someone-explain-to-me-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-what-is-a-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22510434/1547734

Basically flatmap transforms an RDD of N elements into (logically) an RDD of N collections and then flattens it into an RDD of all ELEMENTS of the internal collections.

So when you do  inputRDD.flatMap(x => x(0)) then you convert each element into a string. A string is a collection of characters so the "flattening" portion would turn the entire RDD into an RDD of the resulting characters.

Since RDD are based on scala collections the following http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/ might help understanding it more.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of `flatMap` is to convert a single item into multiple items (i.e. a one-to-many relationship).  For example, for an `RDD[Order]`, where each order is likely to have multiple items, I can use `flatMap` to get an `RDD[Item]` (rather than an `RDD[Seq[Item]]`).

In your case, a `String` is effectively a `Seq[Char]`.  It therefore assumes that what you want to do is take that one string and break it up into its constituent characters.

Now, if what you want is to use `flatMap` to get all of the raw `String`s in your RDD, your `flatMap` function should probably look like this: `x => x`.