# replace strings with ZipWithIndex/ZipWithUniqueID

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to replace a certain string to number using ZipWithIndex OR ZipWithUniqueID

lets say I have this format

```
("u1",("name", "John Sam"))
("u2",("age", "twinty Four"))
("u3",("name", "sam Blake"))
```

I want this result

```
(0,(3,4))
(1,(5,6))
(2,(3,8))
```

what I did is to extract the first element in the key, value pair
so I did

```
val first = file.map(line=> line._1).distinct()
then apply ZipWithIndex
val z1= first.ZipWithIndex()
```

I got result like this

```
("u1",0)
("u2",1)
("u3",2)
```

now I need to take the ids/numbers and change it in my original file. and I need to keep all the distinct ids/numbers in hashTable to be able to look for them later on.
is there any way to do that? Any suggestions?

I hope you got my question

Answer (score 2):

With

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("name", "John"), ("age", "twinty"), ("name", "sam")
))
```

flatten the data:

```
val flat = rdd.flatMap { case (x, y) => Seq(x, y) }
```

get unique values:

```
val unique = flat.distinct
```

Index and collect as map:

```
val map = unique.zipWithIndex.collectAsMap
```

Go back and `map`:

```
val indexed = rdd.map { case (x, y) => (map(x), map(y)) }
```

Enjoy the reuslt

```
indexed.toLocalIterator.foreach(println)
(2,4)
(3,0)
(2,1)
```

**Edit**:

With rewritten questions, replace the first step with:

```
val flat = rdd.flatMap { case (x, (y, z)) => Seq(x, y, z) }
```

and the last step with:

```
val indexed = rdd.map { case (x, (y, z)) => (map(x), (map(y), map(z))) }
```

Comment: Which part didn't work? This code can be executed as is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each

Comment: It looks like you want something else than described in the questions...