# Applying transformations with filter or map which one is faster Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Iam trying to do some transformations on the dataset with spark using scala currently using spark sql but want to shift the code to native scala code. i want to know whether to use filter or map, doing some operations like matching the values in column and get a single column after the transformation into a different dataset.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ''
```

Used to write something like this earlier in spark sql can someone tell me an alternative way to write the same using map or filter on the dataset, and even which one is much faster when compared.

Comment: please provide your input sample and output so that I can suggest what to use

Comment: Right now i had `DateSetWithSparkReadSqlTable.createOrReplaceTempView("TABLE")` and then i had spark sql = `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'YES'` i want to do the same exact thing using filter or map. directly with the dataset instead of using spark sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read documentation from Apache Spark website. This is the link to API documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#package.
Here is a little example -

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"ABC"), (2,"DEF"), (3,"GHI"))).toDF("col1","col2")
val df1 = df.filter("col1 > 1")
df1.show()
val df2 = df1.map(x => x.getInt(0) + 3)
df2.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you also tell me how exactly can i do the same with a map `df.map(row=>{})` and i want to know which might take less time.

Comment: map does not filter rows. Map is used for deriving a value from record and outputs one value for each row. For filtering rows, you have to use filter transformation. I am adding map example to the answer.

Comment: So map takes every row and does some operation on it and returns it back can we use the same logic to skip some rows which are not satisfying the condition and return only those rows which satisfies and create a new df ??    ` val df2 = df1.map(x => if{ x[column][value]>1 return x[column][value]  else skip )
df2.show()` . this is a pseudo code can i do something like above ?? with map ?

Comment: No. map can not skip records. It's input is a record and returns a value. For skipping or creating multiple records from single record, you have to use FlatMap.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example on using FlatMap ? and again which is more effective filter or FlatMap ?

Comment: You can read about map vs flatmap from this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179526/discussion-between-sundeep-pidugu-and-ajay-srivastava).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you need to rewrite your SQL query to DataFrame API. Your query reads all columns from table `TABLE` and filter rows where `COLUMN` is empty. You can do this with DF in the following way:

```
spark.read.table("TABLE")
  .where($"COLUMN".eqNullSafe(""))
  .show(10)
```

Performance will be the same as in your SQL. Use `dataFrame.explain(true)` method to understand what Spark will do.