# Output from map() and flatMap() - what is the difference

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm very new to spark (and programming), and so if you can help me understand the difference between these 2 outputs that would be great.

```
map()
>>> data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'one', 'two']
>>> distData = sc.parallelize(data)
>>> maping = distData.map(lambda x: x.split())
>>> maping.collect()
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['one'], ['two']]                           
>>> for i in maping.take(100): print(i)
... 
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['one']
['two']

FlatMap()

>>> maping = distData.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
>>> maping.collect()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'one', 'two']
>>> for i in maping.take(100): print(i)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
one
two
```

Comment: The duplicate is in Scsala, not pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

A `map` function is a *one to many transformation* while a `flatMap` function is a *one to zero or many transformation*.

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations),

> map(func): Return a new distributed dataset formed by passing each element of the source through a function func.
>
> flatMap(func): Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0
>   or more output items (so func should return a Seq rather than a single
>   item).

You can say for each input value, the `flatMap` outputs a `sequence` which can have 0 or more elements which are flattened to form output RDD.

Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each) which demonstrates a good use case.

Comment: isn't a map function one to one? and a flatmap (may be ) one to many ??

Comment: Yes, it is. Specifically, you can say for each input `flatMap` outputs a sequence which can have 0 or more elements.