# Using coalesce(1) is taking too much time time for writing dataset to s3

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, coalesce, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using coalesce(1) for writing the set of records in s3 bucket in csv process.
which is taking too much time for 505 records.

```
dataset.coalesce(1).write().csv("s3a://bucketname/path");
```

And I want to mention that before this writing process, I'm having a encryption process which is changing value of some fields of the row of dataset. there i'm using repartion(200). As

```
dataset.javaRDD().repartition(200).map(r -> func());
```

if I'm skipping the encyption process, the writing process is not even taking single minute.
What is issue which is causing the process to slow down?
How can I increase the performance?

Comment: if clarification is needed, please ask

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid using coalesce(1) instead use partition by, i suppose the function which you are using to encrypt data is taking a lot of time as it has to iterate through all the records you could change it to flat map and check the preformance

Request you to check [map and flat map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each)

Welcome to the community please do accept the answer if useful.