# Read text file to tuple pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, tuples

I have a question about reading and creating a dataset.
I have a text file which contains:

```
Sunny,Hot,High,Weak,No
Sunny,Hot,High,Strong,No
```

and I implemented this code like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import operator
import math

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Lab 6")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
rawData = sc.textFile("txtfile.data")
data = rawData.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

instead of having a result like this:

```
[(Sunny, Hot, High, Weak, No), (Sunny, Hot, High, Strong, No)]
```

It gave me the result:

```
['Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Weak', 'No', 'Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Strong', 'No']
```

Can anyone show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`map`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each) instead of `flatMap`.

```
data = rawData.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
#[['Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Weak', 'No'], ['Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Strong', 'No']]

#to get list of tuples
data = rawData.map(lambda line: tuple(line.split(",")))
#[('Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Weak', 'No'), ('Sunny', 'Hot', 'High', 'Strong', 'No')]
```

Comment: It said that I havent reached 15 reputation to make this upvote public yet, sorry mate :( I had upvoted the moment I got ur reply :'(

Answer (score 1):

`flatmap` is the combination of `map` (transformation) and flatten, which will create a row for each element in the sub-array.

You want to use the `map` method that will generate a column of type Array of string.